# Getting checked radio button

Tags: c#, bitmap, radio-button

I have made 4 radio buttons and set their tag to wood, diamond, clay, and brick. I want to find the checked one and set a Bitmap property based on the selected radio button. Disregard the fact that it should be split into more methods, that will be done when i refactor. The properties cellBgImage in Map and Cell are null.

```
 void setCellBgImage()
        {
            string cellBgImage = "";
            foreach (Control c in myMap.myForm.Controls)
            {
                if (c is RadioButton)
                {
                    RadioButton radio = c as RadioButton;
                    if (radio.Checked)
                    {
                        cellBgImage = radio.Tag.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            switch (cellBgImage)
            {
                case "wood":
                    myMap.cellBgImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("Images/wood.png");
                    break;
                case "diamond":
                    myMap.cellBgImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("Images/diamond.png");
                    break;
                case "clay":
                    myMap.cellBgImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("Images/clay.png");
                    break;
                case "brick":
                    myMap.cellBgImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("Images/brick.png");
                    break;
            }
            foreach (Cell cell in myMap.myCells)
            {
                cell.myBgImage = myMap.cellBgImage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? are you able to find the `RadioButtons` ?

Comment: well it simply doesn't find the controls you are looking for,
do you have any container, like a panel, update panel or whatever ?

Comment: Maybe your radio buttons are in a panel, do you check it ?

Comment: @Omribitan Yes. I can also see that one of them is checked with the debugger.

Comment: @losSebos Yes, they are all inside panel1.

Comment: @AsfK They are in a panel. Does this change things?

Comment: @Omribitan there is no way to check the tag value in the debugger. I'm not certain that tag is to be used in the way i am

Comment: @user2602079: yes, do the foreach on panel1

Comment: the best way to do this is to use the : "Panel1.Controls".
When using the "form.Controls", it won't search inside each Panel, UpdatePanel etc...
You can even optimise your code :

foreach (Control c in myMap.myForm.Controls)            
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
              RadioButton radio = c as RadioButton;
              cellBgImage = (radio.Checked) ? Radio.Tag.ToString():"";
            }

Answer (score 1):

Add a default case to the switch so when none of them are checked you still get a value in myMap.cellBgImage.

```
      default:
            myMap.cellBgImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("Images/brick.png");
            break;
```

Comment: I added the default and it still didnt set cellBgImage which is strange because the whole method used to be just that one line that sets it hardcoded and it worked.

Comment: Are you sure that the method is being called ? Try to put assertion points Debug.Assert(myMap.cellBgImage != null, "Still null.."); after the switch is out and see if it pops up.

Comment: Wait no only the default case is set. I was calling it wrong but also it doesn't work. Fail. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As you write at the comments your RB are in panel1. so you should do the Foreach like this:

```
foreach (Control c in this.panel1.Controls)
```